# So i havent upgraded my PopOS 21.04 in a while and i keep getting this error message when trying to upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg, pop-os, pkg-config

`dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libxpm4_1%3a3.5.12-1_amd64.deb (--unpack): trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libxpm4/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of package libxpm4:amd64 Errors were encountered while processing: /var/cache/apt/archives/libxpm4_1%3a3.5.12-1_amd64.deb`

I have tried:

`sudo mv /usr/share/doc/libxpm4/changelog.Debian.gz $HOME` Although this seems to be kinda working as it momentarily fixes my upgrade although I need to keep typing this with the new package it tells me to move to $HOME

I also tried sudo apt-get --fix-broken install and reconfiguring dpkg but I still have the same issue.

Comment: Did you do anything else? Like e.g. change the apt sources or fiddle with the release?

Comment: I looked through other forums saying I needed to delete some items or folders which I did but I can’t remember exactly what. I don’t think I fiddled with the release in any way tho.