# Getting this error when trying to install Tillix

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg, pop-os

```
libllvm11 : Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 12) but 11.1.0-1ubuntu1~21.04 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I haven't upgraded my system in a few weeks and I'm suddenly getting a bunch of errors when upgrading or downloading items.

Comment: Have you run `apt update`?

Comment: Tell us which Ubuntu version you are on, and as Bib noted, probably apt update ; apt upgrade first.

Comment: It’s solved - It wasn’t apt update although I do have a issue with that as well: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/706250/so-i-havent-upgraded-my-popos-21-04-in-a-while-and-i-keep-getting-this-error-mes

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same issue try updating and upgrading the system, although for me aptitude is broken so I had to find another solution.